# Configure a Proxy Array Consisting of 3 Squid Proxy Servers

Tags: apache, web, webserver, squid

I am trying to configure and install 3 squid proxy servers using CentOS. I have compiled and installed three separate servers in the following directories:

"/usr/local/squid"
"/usr/local/squid2"
"/usr/local/squid3"

From here I am completely lost. I need to use squid for load balancing and I only have one ip address to do it (localhost). I was assigned 3 separate ports as well. This first squid server works as a load balancer. It then forwards the client request to the second and third squid server based on a load balance rule. If no cached copy then forward back to the origin server.

The first squid server should use the CARP protocol and "1/3" of the client requests should be sent to the second squid server and "2/3" should be sent to the third squid server.

Any ideas on the squid.conf file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use LVS:

```
ipvsadm -A -t x.x.x.x:3128 -s wlc
ipvsadm -a -t x.x.x.x:3128 -r localhost:3128
ipvsadm -a -t x.x.x.x:3128 -r localhost:3129
ipvsadm -a -t x.x.x.x:3128 -r localhost:3130
```

x.x.x.x is your local IP.